# What does $\mathcal{L}$ stands for in back propagation?

Tags: neural-networks, backpropagation, derivative

I am trying to learn how to do deep neural networks with this [Ipython notebook](https://github.com/andersy005/deep-learning-specialization-coursera/blob/master/01-Neural-Networks-and-Deep-Learning/week4/Programming%20Assignments/Building%20your%20Deep%20Neural%20Network%20-%20Step%20by%20Step/Building%2Byour%2BDeep%2BNeural%2BNetwork%2B-%2BStep%2Bby%2BStep%2Bv3.ipynb). I'm puzzled about notations in  linear backward learning section.

For layer $l$, the linear part is: $Z^{[l]} = W^{[l]} A^{[l-1]} + b^{[l]}$ (followed by an activation). I want to get $(dW^{[l]}, db^{[l]} dA^{[l-1]})$.

The course suppose that I have already calculated the derivative $dZ^{[l]} = \frac{\partial \mathcal{L} }{\partial Z^{[l]}}$. Yet, What does $\mathcal{L}$ stands for in the derivative $dZ^{[l]} = \frac{\partial \mathcal{L} }{\partial Z^{[l]}}$ means ? I have never seen it defined here.

Comment: Your links are behind the wall, one needs an account to see it

Comment: @Aksakal, sure. I've updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It probably means "loss" as in "loss function" but as with everything else in mathematical notation, this is merely a convention and anyone can define any symbol to mean anything. The only way to be sure is to ask the author.